# Creating a logo for a PDF application, which symbol should I use?

Tags: logo, pdf, copyright, legal

I'm developing a Mac PDF application and I'm at the tedious step to study a proper fancy logo.

Is it ok to use the well known Adobe symbol of PDF inside my logo?

[image: Adobe PDF logo]

Do you know another symbol that is used to represent a PDF application?
Should I stick with just the PDF word without any symbol avoiding any legal problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That symbol is an Adobe trademark. The [guidelines for use of their trademarks](http://www.adobe.com/misc/trade.html) are pretty specific, as with any company. You would definitely be in violation if you used their logo in your product without permission.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite normal to use a white paper (styles vary) with a small box containing the text `PDF`. If you position the box somewhere else (not upper left like the official logo) you would be safe. It is important that you don't touch anything that can look like any of the trade-marked designs. Especially, I would advice you to NOT use the "curly thing" in the Adobe PDF logo or anything like it. Also not use the name "Adobe" in any way.

Basically, I advice you to read thoroughly the guidelines that @Alan pointed to in [his answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4184/creating-a-logo-for-a-pdf-application-which-symbol-should-i-use/4186#4186) to avoid any pitfalls.